# How to stop umount all when I exit ssh session?

Tags: ssh, umount

So when i'm logged into Lucid via ssh, and type `exit` to end the session, `umount -a` is run first by the system. I see the follow message before it logs me out:

```
umount: /home: device is busy.
    (In some cases useful info about processes that use
     the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))<p>
umount: /var/run: device is busy.
    (In some cases useful info about processes that use
     the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))<p>
umount: /dev/shm: device is busy.
    (In some cases useful info about processes that use
     the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))<p>
umount: /dev: device is busy.
    (In some cases useful info about processes that use
     the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))<p>
umount: /: device is busy.
    (In some cases useful info about processes that use
     the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))<p>
```

How can i stop this?

Comment: The question seems abandoned. My guess is the OP has a log out script of some kind.

Answer (score -1):

however, seems that it doesn't unmount the folders at all..

well let's do a read to ``man on_exit man page, maybe some configuration on the machine you are log in is playing with you.